# how to fix input string was not in a correct format on login page .aspx.vb format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, input

```
Dim userExists As Int32 = Convert
           .ToInt32(ExecuteScallar_AJAY("SELECT Count(w02_TeacherID_child) " 
           & " FROM wUsers WHERE ( (LCase(w03_WebUserName) = '" 
           & userUsername.Trim.ToLower & "') " 
           & " AND (LCase(w04_WebUserPassword) = '" 
           & userPassword.Trim.ToLower & "') );", "vijay"))
```

How to fix input string was not in a correct format on login page .aspx.vb format?

Comment: There is a bigger problem with this code and that is it's vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: There is also the problem that the user password appears to be stored in plain text in the database.